# Removing duplicate names in FeaturePopups cluster tooltips and popups

Tags: openlayers-2, clustering

I am using [FeaturePopups control](https://github.com/jorix/OL-FeaturePopups) to show tooltips and popups for clusters.
I have features connected (ends of road segments) with the same names.

Is it possible to remove them from tooltips and popups, so to have a list with unique names?

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to rewrite the html list popup preparation using event `"beforepopupdisplayed"` on option `popupListOptions.eventListeners` as:

```js
var fpControl = new OpenLayers.Control.FeaturePopups({        
  popupListOptions: {eventListeners: {
    "beforepopupdisplayed": function(e){
        var html = [],
            htmlAux = [];
        for (var i = 0, iLen = e.selection.length; i < iLen; i++) {
            var sel = e.selection[i],
                layerObj = sel.layerObj;                
            for (var ii = 0, iiLen = sel.features.length; ii < iiLen; ii++) {
                // ******** FILTER DUPLUCATES HERE ******************
                if (true) { 
                    htmlAux.push(layerObj.renderTemplate(
                        layerObj.templates.item, sel.features[ii])
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        html.push(layerObj.renderTemplate(
            layerObj.templates.list, {
                layer: sel.layer,
                count: sel.features.length,
                html: htmlAux.join('\n')
            }
        ));
        e.html = html.join('\n');
    }
  }},
  ...
```

For tooltips it is a bit more simple, not much.

WARNING: To use this trick you should update the control, today it has made ​​a small adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove popups with some basic coding.

```
var allpps = map.popups;
for(var i=0; i < allpps.length; i++){
   if(allpps[i].id.indexOf('blabla') > -1){ // You write what you want to put here.
      map.removePopup(map.popups[i]);
   };
};
```